# MySQL InnoDB VARCHAR performance versus TEXT on inserts

Tags: mysql, performance, text, insert, varchar

Using MySQL 5 InnoDB should varchar be used over text in a table where you expect many inserts? I intend to store text with a maximum length of 2000 characters.

Comment: Here's a link to the max sizes and such: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: @Mihai, VARCHAR has a max length of 65535 bytes since MySQL 5.0.3. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

VARCHAR and TEXT are stored identically in MySQL's InnoDB storage engine. There is no performance difference.

See [Blob Storage in Innodb](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/) for lots of detailed explanation.

The only difference between these two data types is that VARCHAR can have a DEFAULT, whereas TEXT cannot.

Comment: PS: I assume you're using InnoDB, not MyISAM, because *no one* should use MyISAM.

Comment: Yes using InnoDB, I've updated the post to make that explicit, thanks.

Comment: Oh and just bought a certain book ... 'SQL Antipatterns' :)

Comment: Can I clarify you mean there are no performance differences _for the INSERT_ (as per the question). There are certainly performance differences between the two e.g. for SELECT, TEXT fields force temporary tables to go to disk which can be a significant performance hit.

Comment: @scipilot, right, there should be no difference on INSERT. Behavior of these two data types changes regarding temp tables during some SELECT queries, as you mention.